# Azure static webapp Oryx github build breaks

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app, oryx

Im trying to test different things on Azure, and i have tried to setup a static webapp.
The github repo consists of nothing really.

[image]

These files are pretty much empty. Whenever i push something to the repo, the build triggers, but fails with the error `Oryx built the app folder but was unable to determine the location of the app artifacts. Please specify the app artifact location through the Github workflow file.`

Im uncertain of what it means with artifacts. This tiny webapp doesnt have any real build or anything
In the *azure-static-web-apps-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx.yml* file the app_artifact_location is " "

Not really sure which artifacts its looking for, or what they are really.

Comment: what is your YAML file. put that here.

Comment: Which YAML file? Dont think i have one

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview

- Python-based frontends are not supported. Clients are served *statically* and are browser-based apps. The build system (*0ryx*) likely unable to determine the framework and is generating the error message you are seeing.
- The default web page that is expected is *index.html*. It looks like you may have misspelled it = *index.hmtl*